# How to aggregate all columns of 2 json arrays with same keys

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to go from

```
var var1 = [
  {key:'key1',value1:'value11'},
  {key:'key2',value1:'value12'}
];

var var2 = [
  {key:'key1',value2:'value21'},
  {key:'key2',value2:'value22'}
];
```

to here

```
var var3 = [
  {key:'key1',value1:'value11',value2:'value21'},
  {key:'key2',value1:'value12',value2:'value22'}
];
```

What's the easiest way ?

Comment: There's an underscore.js function that helps to merge objects. Working on a solution using this.

Comment: note: these are not JSON arrays, these are javascript arrays - on fact, there's no such thing as a JSON array as JSON is simply a string

Comment: What do you mean by same key? Looks like a non trivial type of merge to me so you might have to loop through one array and compare matching key values to know how to build your 3rd, new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Slower solution

One solution would be to just iterate over array1 and, for each object, merge it if an object with its key already exists in array2.

This solution would have constant space but quadratic time `O(arr1.length) * O(arr2.length)` because for every object in array1, we're searching for a match in array2.

```js
var var1=[{key:"key1",value1:"value11"},{key:"key2",value1:"value12"}],var2=[{key:"key1",value2:"value21"},{key:"key2",value2:"value22"}];

// O(N*M) time, O(1) space
function mergeQuadratic(arr1, arr2) {
  const result = [];

  arr1.forEach(obj1 => {
    // try to find a match for the current arr1 object by searching through arr2
    const obj2 = arr2.find(obj2 => obj2.key === obj1.key);

    // if we found a match, we can merge these two objects
    if (obj2) {
      result.push(Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2));
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(mergeQuadratic(var1, var2));
```

ES5 version:

```js
var var1=[{key:"key1",value1:"value11"},{key:"key2",value1:"value12"}],var2=[{key:"key1",value2:"value21"},{key:"key2",value2:"value22"}];

// O(N*M) time, O(1) space
function mergeQuadratic(arr1, arr2) {
  var result = [];
  arr1.forEach(function(obj1) {
    // try to find a match for the current arr1 object by searching through arr2
    var obj2 = arr2.find(function(obj2) {
      return obj2.key === obj1.key
    });

    // if we found a match, we can merge these two objects
    if (obj2) {
      result.push(Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2));
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(mergeQuadratic(var1, var2));
```

#### Faster solution

An improvement to increase the speed is to tradeoff some space and create a map from array2 so we can reduce the lookup time for a matching key to be constant, giving us a linear run time `O(array1.length) + O(array2.length)` and linear space `O(array2.length)`:

```js
var var1=[{key:"key1",value1:"value11"},{key:"key2",value1:"value12"}],var2=[{key:"key1",value2:"value21"},{key:"key2",value2:"value22"}];

// O(N+M) time, O(N) space
function mergeLinear(arr1, arr2) {
  // create a map of key->obj for every object in arr2
  const map = arr2.reduce((map, curr) => {
    map.set(curr.key, curr);
    return map;
  }, new Map());

  const result = [];

  arr1.forEach(obj1 => {
    // check almost instantly if a matching object exists
    const obj2 = map.get(obj1.key); // <-- Constant time lookup

    // if we found a match, we can merge these two objects
    if (obj2) {
      result.push(Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2));
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(mergeLinear(var1, var2));
```

ES5 version:

```js
var var1=[{key:"key1",value1:"value11"},{key:"key2",value1:"value12"}],var2=[{key:"key1",value2:"value21"},{key:"key2",value2:"value22"}];

// O(N+M) time, O(N) space
function mergeLinear(arr1, arr2) {
  // create a map of key->obj for every object in arr2
  var map = arr2.reduce(function(map, curr) {
    map[curr.key] = curr;
    return map;
  }, Object.create(null));

  var result = [];

  arr1.forEach(function(obj1) {
    // check almost instantly if a matching object exists
    var obj2 = map[obj1.key]; // <-- Constant time lookup

    // if we found a match, we can merge these two objects
    if (obj2) {
      result.push(Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2));
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(mergeLinear(var1, var2));
```

Comment: weird: I tried your 2nd snippet with my datas and key always give id "autres" in console

Comment: @user310291 what do you mean by "autres"?

Comment: just put it in jsfiddle

Comment: I mean the key is always "autres"

Comment: @user310291 I tried it and it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/a72otsmv/3/

Comment: OK I'll check my code in my app again. I marked your answer as right one thanks.

Comment: @user310291 no problem mate, glad to help. let me know if you're still finding a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) (you can test it out on the console there)

I'll leave it as an exercise to make this a one-liner using `_.filter` and `_.map`

```
function extendArrayByKey(var1, var2) {
  for (obj of var1) {
    var key = obj.key;
    for (obj2 of var2) {
      if (obj2.key == key) {
        _.extend(obj, obj2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this modified the objects in `var1` with shallow copies of the values in `var2`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple merge, if your keys are always going to be named like the names you provided.  If the names could change, then this solution will have to modified.

This solution does not mutate either of the existing arrays.  The function returns a new array.

```js
var var1 = [
  {key:'key1',value1:'value11'},
  {key:'key2',value1:'value12'}
];

var var2 = [
  {key:'key1',value2:'value21'},
  {key:'key2',value2:'value22'}
];


function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArray = arr1;

  newArray.forEach(function (obj1) {
    arr2.forEach(function (obj2) {
      if (obj1.key === obj2.key) {
        obj1.value2 = obj2.value2;
      }
    });
  });

  return newArray;
}

var var3 = mergeArrays(var1, var2);

console.log(var3);
```

Comment: I'd like to not have "value2" hard-coded : is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, using the `Object.assign()` that some of the other answers provide.  That will merge all properties, regardless of name.

Answer (score 1):

For good browsers (not IE, but polyfills for [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) and for [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) are available)

```
var var3 = var1.map(function(o1) {
    return Object.assign({}, o1, var2.find(function(o2) {
       return o2.key === o1.key;
    }));
});
```

or in modern speak

```
var var3 = var1.map(o1 => Object.assign({}, o1, var2.find(o2 => o2.key === o1.key)));
```